# Replace # in vb script

Tags: validation, vbscript

I have this line in vb script:

```
fileCheck = Right(objLookFile.name, len(objLookFile.name) - len("Audit_######_"))
```

the `Audit_######_` takes 6 digits for now. I got a situation where I have files with 7 digits and 8.
ex of file : Audit_1002611_Comnpany_MTH_11_2013.00001.txt

How I change the `######` to accept any number of digits?

```
        dim lookFor
    lookFor = fiRef(i_fi) & "_" & AIOType(i_type) & "_" & Right("00" &    (month(processDate + 1)), 2) & "_" & Year(processDate + 1) & ".00001.txt"
    dim minLen
    minLen = len(lookFor)
    dim objLookFolder, objLookFile
    set objLookFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(AIODVDDir)
    For each objLookFile in objLookFolder.files
        if Len(objLookFile.name) >= minLen then
            dim fileCheck
            fileCheck = Right(objLookFile.name, len(objLookFile.name) - len("Audit_######_"))
            if (Left(objLookFile.name, len("Audit_")) = "Audit_") AND (fileCheck = LookFor) then
                'found the audit file
```

Thank you

Comment: Is "Audit_######" something that can be provided to a variable?  Then just replace "Audit_######" with the incoming string?

Comment: Jimmy I have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're not *doing* anything with `"Audit_######_"` other than getting it's length.  It *looks* like a hack-y way to just strip off the first 13 characters.

A *smarter* way may be to get everything after the second underscore :

```
fileCheck = mid(objLookFile.name, instr( instr(objLookFile.name, "_") + 1 , "_")+1)
```

Comment: I got this error though :  Invalid procedure call or argument: 'mid'

Comment: Fixed :) used fileCheck = mid(objLookFile.name, instr(2,objLookFile.name, "A") ) because the 2 is always A and there is always one Abefore that :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to handle this. Using string operations as [D Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19980873/1630171) suggested is one way. Another is to split the file name at underscores and examine the fragments:

```
arr = Split(objLookFile.Name, "_", 3)
If UBound(arr) = 3 Then
  If arr(0) = "Audit" And IsNumeric(arr(1)) And arr(2) = lookFor Then
    ...
  End If
End If
```

Using a regular expression is probably the best approach, though:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "Audit_\d+_" & fiRef(i_fi) & "_" & AIOType(i_type) _
  & "_" & Right("00" & (month(processDate + 1)), 2) _
  & "_" & Year(processDate + 1) & "\.00001\.txt"

For Each objLookFile In objFSO.GetFolder(AIODVDDir).Files
  If re.Test(objLookFile.Name) Then
    ...
  End If
Next
```

`\d+` will match one or more digits. If you want to match a limited number of digits (e.g. at least 6 and at most 8 digits) replace that part of the pattern with `\d{6,8}`.